# d3js v5 Resize Grouped Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to resize a grouped bar chart with a resize() function.

```
function resize(){

    width = parseInt(d3.select(".c_chart").style("width"), 10);

    x0.rangeRound([margin.left, width-margin.right]);
    x1.rangeRound([margin.left,x0.bandwidth()-margin.right])

    yAxis.tickSize(width);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth());

    svg.selectAll(".x_axis")
        .call(xAxis)    
        .selectAll("text")
        .call(wrap, x0.bandwidth());

}
```

[image]

When I start to resize the window, x-axis is ok but the x-position of my recent don't "follow" the ticks of my x-axis.
[image]

Then, I suspect that the problem is due to x- attribute but how can I fix that?

Here is my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/XEoM7lsBvZQmY87Wz1SP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class (`gbar`) to the `g` containing the group

```
svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; })
    .attr("class", "gbar")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height-margin.bottom - y(d.value); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });
```

In the resize function update the translation

```
    svg.selectAll(".gbar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });
```

and update the size of the SVG

```
svg
   .attr("width",width)
   .attr("height",height);
```

Don't take the margin in the `x1` scale

```
const x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05)
    .domain(keys)
    //.rangeRound([margin.left,x0.bandwidth()-margin.right])
    .rangeRound([0,x0.bandwidth()]);

// resize()
//x1.rangeRound([margin.left,x0.bandwidth()-margin.right])
x1.rangeRound([0,x0.bandwidth()])
```

The only thing left to fix is the y-axis grid line,........